# Mouse covered by canvas rectangle in JavaFX

Tags: canvas, javafx, mouse

I have a canvas in JavaFX with two rectangles. The outer I draw only once at the beginning and the inner I redraw every 0.25 seconds. When I enter the canvas I change the mouse to crosshair and back to default when leaving.

My problem is, that the mouse is covered by the innern rectangle.
Should I redraw the mouse or is there something like z-index in css existing in JavaFX?[image]

Comment: For debugging help provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like z-order in javafx but not, if you draw everything on a `Canvas`. On a `Canvas` simply the order of drawing operations is important. If you draw the inner rect after the cursor, the cursor will be covered by the later drawing operation.

However since you use the same cursor for the whole canvas. I recommend actually using a cursor to change the look of the cursor. You can use [`ImageCursor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/ImageCursor.html) with a image of the crosshair for this purpose:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("crosshair.png").toExternalForm());

// create cursor from image with hotspot at center
Cursor crosshair = new ImageCursor(img, img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2);

canvas.setCursor(crosshair);
```